# Create transcription from 'UnmixedMeetingAudio' buffer as soon as those are received - bot with application hosted media

Tags: botframework, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api, azure-speech

I have created a bot using bot framework (.net) with application hosted media using the sample provided [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples). Bot attends any incoming peer to peer or group calls in Microsoft Teams. While in the meeting I am able to receive audio buffers as participants speak up in `AudioMediaReceived` event handler inside `CallHandler.cs` class provided in the samples. Now I want to generate transcript out of it. I want some guidance about:

Can this be done at the end of the meeting, I am confused as it's stated on a number of places ([1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls.Media/))([2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-media#application-hosted-media-local-hosting))  that

> "You may not use this SDK to record or otherwise persist media content
> from calls or meetings that your bot accesses"

.

In which scenario this fits? Is it possible to generate wave(.wav) file out of the byte array (UnmixedAudioBuffer data) received and use that for transcription at the end of the meeting?

Since we receive audio frames at a very quick pace (50 frames per second), If I am to generate the transcript asynchronously and real time, how should I do it. Is it about converting buffer data to .wav or in memory stream and using some cloud speech service/API?
There's a speech service provided by Microsoft as well as speech to text resource provided by Google cloud.
your guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: You say this is stated in a number of places: "You may not use this SDK to record or otherwise persist media content from calls or meetings that your bot accesses." Can you link to one of them?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Added links to documentations, updated the question

Comment: Thank you for the update. It looks to me like that quote is saying you're not allowed to do what you're trying to do because it's a privacy violation. Do you understand that point? Also, can you help us understand more about the purpose of your bot? It sounds like you want it to record meetings, so why not just have someone push the record button?

Comment: The purpose is not the recording, but just to create a transcript out of audio media that is received during the meeting or on real time.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just use transcript software to generate a transcript from the recording instead of using a bot?

Comment: sorry? from where to get the recording that we need to feed to transcript 'software'? and which softwares are available that can be used?

Comment: Like I said, you can push the record button. And Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for software recommendations, and that's not really my area of expertise anyway. Would you please answer my question? Would it be acceptable?

Comment: yes, if there is a way to programmatically access the recording so we could use it for further processing, we can try this approach too

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to try to get a bot to transcribe meetings for you for the reasons you've already seen. However, you're in luck because Microsoft already transcribes meetings automatically.

You can record a meeting in Teams by following the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/record-a-meeting-in-teams-34dfbe7f-b07d-4a27-b4c6-de62f1348c24

If you save the recorded meeting to Microsoft Stream then you can even edit the transcript. If you save the meeting to OneDrive and SharePoint then this page implies the feature should be available in the future: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-the-transcript-of-a-meeting-recording-in-teams-2f461386-e39a-4444-b9e2-5787da1da11b